# zxing run time exception into android application

Tags: java, android, zxing, barcode-scanner, scanning

I am successfully able to run the zxing project.

Now, I am integrating the zxing with my project to integrated scan application.

```
05-16 07:21:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(5512): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-411
05-16 07:21:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(5512): Process: com.tallymaster9.tradetec, PID: 5512
05-16 07:21:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(5512): java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
05-16 07:21:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(5512):     case expressions must be constant expressions
05-16 07:21:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(5512):     case expressions must be constant expressions
05-16 07:21:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(5512):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.DecodeHandler.handleMessage(DecodeHandler.java:57)
05-16 07:21:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(5512):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-16 07:21:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(5512):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-16 07:21:01.380: E/AndroidRuntime(5512):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.DecodeThread.run(DecodeThread.java:110)
```

Can any body having this type of problem?

Comment: for what QRcode or Barcode

Answer (score 1):

As from log I found that the code you are facing error only on    `DecodeHandler.handleMessage(DecodeHandler.java:57)`

& **IF** you are using zxing basic android code there are switch statements.

```
switch (message.what) {
  case R.id.decode:
    decode((byte[]) message.obj, message.arg1, message.arg2);
    break;
  case R.id.quit:
    running = false;
    Looper.myLooper().quit();
    break;
}
```

I am facing same issue for this. Just turn this statement into if .. else one.
click on the **swith** `ctrl+1`  it directly covert your code to if else.

This way I solved mine. 
let me know if you have any query for this.

Comment: That is because since ADT 14 you are not allowed to have resource constants as 'case' constants convert them into if.. else as shown in answer by AndroEmbedded

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is come when you not completely link zxing library with our project, if you are working on QRCode or BarCode then You can learn form **[barcode tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162)** and this **[qrcode and barcode](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-barcode-and-qr-scanner-example/)**

[**Complete code for Qr&BarCodeScanner**](http://rehman-furniture.com/attaullahcs/stackdir/QR_BR_CodeReder.7z) hope it will help you...